# apache poi vs python xlrd

Tags: java, python, excel, apache-poi

I was going to use apache poi or python xlrd on linux to read spreadsheets in a program on linux. I am biased towards python xlrd but apache poi seems like a more complete project to me (probably since its supported by the apache foundation). What would be a better choice (I am biased towards python but still..) ? I would like to be able to read most of the versions of excel and read macros.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the complexity of your needs, you could potentially just use the [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) CLI. Tika handles talking to POI (and other libraries) and will give you back a XHTML or plain text version of the document. If you just want a simple linux command, that might be good enough.

Otherwise, it may depend on what your Java skills are like. POI should do everything you need, but you'll need to write a bit of code to grab the bits that interest you. Have a look at the [quick guide](http://tika.apache.org/) to get you started.

(I don't know about xlrd, sorry)

Comment: I basically wanted to run this on a web server. If its java then I think I will have to write jsps to let people hit it. However, I do need more features - like extracting formulas etc and not just plain text. Apache POI would be good for that I guess ?

Comment: Have a play with Tika, as you might find it does give what you need WRT formulas and the like, and the Tika integration with SOLR may help on the web front. Otherwise, there are plenty of nice Java web frameworks out there that'll let you render your data extracted from POI without needing to touch a JSP!

Answer (score 0):

One option to potentially give the best of both worlds would be to leverage Apache POI via Jython (python syntax with java interop).

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/jython/PoiExample) is a dated jython example... i believe this will need to be changed with the newer version of POI.